# How do I add values to a combo box from this in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a launcher for the game "Minecraft" , and I use a library. So basically I am trying to add values into a combo box  from a list , but it gives me a error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'object[]
```

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CmlLib.Core;
using CmlLib.Core.Auth;

namespace cosmic_cord_installer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var path = new MinecraftPath();

            var launcher = new CMLauncher(path);

            var versions = launcher.GetAllVersions();
            foreach (var item in versions)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(item.Name);
            }
        }

        private async void bunifuButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 256;

            var path = new MinecraftPath();

            var launcher = new CMLauncher(path);

            var versions = await launcher.GetAllVersionsAsync();
            foreach (var item in versions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            var launchOption = new MLaunchOption
            {
                MaximumRamMb = 4096,
                Session = MSession.GetOfflineSession("hello"), // Login Session. ex) Session = MSession.GetOfflineSession("hello")
                VersionType = "CosmicLauncher",
                GameLauncherName = "CosmicLauncher",
                GameLauncherVersion = "2",
            };

            var process = await launcher.CreateProcessAsync("1.12.2", launchOption); // vanilla
                                                                                     // var process = await launcher.CreateProcessAsync("1.12.2-forge1.12.2-14.23.5.2838", launchOption); // forge
                                                                                     // var process = await launcher.CreateProcessAsync("1.12.2-LiteLoader1.12.2"); // liteloader
                                                                                     // var process = await launcher.CreateProcessAsync("fabric-loader-0.11.3-1.16.5") // fabric-loader

            process.Start();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bunifuButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C explorer %appdata%\\.minecraft";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line with the error:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(item.Name);
```

How would I add the values in another way , or how would I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddRange` method is for add a range of value.

Use `Add(item.Name)`